# How to optimise a toothpaste tube / moisturiser squeeze tube? I am trying to find the least surface area to volume ratio.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, analysis, partial-differential-equations

So that the least amount of material is used/wasted in making a tube. I initially tried modelling it using area of revolution but it's impossible since the tube is tapered at the end.

I then decided to split the tube into two parts so I found an equation for the top part of the tube.

v=(4+pi)/12)pi x radius squared x height

Surface area = 2 pi r h

Does anyone know how I can optimise these two equations using Lagrange Multiplier or just in general

or other methods I can use to optimise the tube?

thank you

---

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated is not well defined. The surface area to volume ratio of a closed solid typically decreases with increasing volume, implying you should let volume go to infinity to minimize the ratio.  For instance, in the case of a sphere, the ratio is $\frac{4\pi r^2}{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3}\propto \frac{1}{r}$.

A more meaningful question would be what closed shape minimizes surface area subject to having some given volume. The answer here would then be a sphere (a consequence of the isoperimetric inequality).

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#Isoperimetric_inequality_in_higher_dimensions) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-area-to-volume_ratio) if interested.

Comment: it would be how I can make a toothpaste tube more eco friendly so that less material is used (for example, when a cylinder is optimised, the optimal height to radius ratio would be 1:2 [ h opt = 2 r opt], and I want to find this optimal ratio for a toothpaste tube

I'm sorry I don't really understand the first part of your comment

Comment: @yenpng The motivation for the question should be included in the question itself, not in the comment sections.

Comment: @yenpng, you will have to clarify what qualifies as a "toothpaste tube" in that case..

Comment: ohhh ok I'm so sorry I'm knew to this place thank you!

Comment: @Golden_Ratio, toothpaste tube was used to name the shape since I didn't know what the name of the shape is haha, do u hv any idea what shape it is, and the specific shape I would like to optimise would be the image as attached above, it's for my Ib exams and I'm rlly struggling ahaha

Comment: No idea what that shape is called.  I would be surprised if that's a practice exam question though without further info; could you share the original question?  Absent any info, the general idea would be to make it as "spherical" as possible subject to whatever constraints are imposed.